# Uncaught Rangeerror: Callstack exceeded when trying to convert Int8Array to String/JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexeddb, uint8array

I'm using webassembly to fetch JSON data, and save it to IndexedDB. I can manage to get it as Int8Array from the IndexedDB, and convert it to string then parse to JSON when it is small enough, but when the data is too large it gives an error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Screenshot of the console logs:

[image: Console]

The bit of code responsible:

```
function ConvertToJSON(result){
    console.log("= Converting to JSON =");
    console.log(result);
    let int8View = new Int8Array(result[0]);
    console.log(int8View);
    let str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, int8View); //RangeError when array too large...
    let json = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(json);
    AddJSONToPage(json);
}
```

Is there a way to circumvent this issue? Do I need to splice the array into smaller bits and convert, then paste it together, and if so how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), functions have a hard-coded limit of 65,536 arguments passed into functions. With your Int8Array having more than 600,000 elements, your `apply` call dies due to 10x more arguments supplied than can be. You could split it up as you say, but you can also call `reduce` on the Int8Array and do it all in one pass:

```
int8View.reduce((arr, int8) => arr.concat( String.fromCharCode(int8) ), []);
```